# Android Glance Widget - Corner Radius Cliping on Android 12-

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, glance-appwidget, glance

Using Glance beta-01

To handle cornerRadius on Android 12-, we cannot use the `GlanceModifier.cornerRadius`. So using a custom xml background does the trick, but the Cliping (hiding the content overflowing the radius) only works on the targeted element.

So, is it possible to Clip the **content/child of a component** when applying a layout with corner Radius on Android S- ?

Example :

```
Box(modifier = GlanceModifier().background(R.drawable.test)) {
    Text("blabla)
}
```

with test.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="@color/test" />

    <corners android:radius="@dimen/corner_radius_outside" />
</shape>
```

would render as something like :

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Glance in Android 12+ supports clipping the content via the cornerRadius property. On Android 12- clipping is not supported for remote views, and you should use the padding properties to have your content avoid problem areas.

See : [RemoteViewsCompat](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/core/widget/RemoteViewsCompat#(android.widget.RemoteViews).setViewClipToOutline(kotlin.Int,kotlin.Boolean))

Comment: Argh that + the fact that we cannot "tint" a shape drawable make Glance a huge pain but thanks...

Comment: @Jscti did you manage to find a solution for the no "tint" problem? Right now I always use an already colored drawable as background but it feels wrong.